# How do I disable user pictures?

Tags: users, 8

In Drupal 7, you can disable user pictures just by unchecking the appropriate box on the Config -> People screen.

How can I disable user pictures in Drupal 8?  I see that the default D8 install adds an image field `user_picture` at `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`, but I assume that it would be better to somehow disable this than just to delete it.

For now, I don't want user pictures to be shown or used in any way, unless I decide to re-enable them later.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want to delete the field, you can exclude the field from input:

```
/admin/config/people/accounts/form-display
```

and from output:

```
/admin/config/people/accounts/display
```

Answer (score 3):

I am using the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module to accomplish this by only lettings admins see the field. This way I do not disrupt what is there by default if things change in the future.